# How to disable automatic invoice generation in magento 2.4.0?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment-methods, magento2.4, invoice

I am using custom Online Payment method (N-Genius Online) there Invoice is generating automatically. I want to stop Auto invoice generation in magento 2.4.0.

Kindly help me on this.

Kind regards,

Comment: Hi there, please describe in a more explanatory way for which payment method? so it will be helpful to guess, For example, is it an offline shipping method or an online shipping method, and what method is it, did u check the configurations for it?

Comment: This is online payment method.
https://docs.ngenius-payments.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System->Configuration->Sales->paymentMethods

There you will see your custom Online Payment method(N-Genius Online)
click on configure button in right side of your custom Online Payment method
in payment action field select "Authorize Only" from the dropdown.

In this payment, an action invoice will not be created after the order is created successfully. Admin will have to manually create invoices from the backend from the order management section.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. Just go to System->Configuration->Sales Emails and under the tab "Invoice" set Enable to NO.

Comment: Kindly read my question again, your answer is about we cannot send invoice to customer. That's already i have stopped.